# How to switch on\off frontend form validation for some fields in yii2?

Tags: jquery, validation, yii2

I have got difficult form in yii2 view, where some fields show or hide. It decide from user field choises, select options in the form. I write this frontend logic with custom jquery file. All is ok. But when I submit form - hidden fields stay without validation and nothing is happend.How I can kill ofrontend validation, when fields are hiiden and switch on it, when fields are visible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To disable client side validation. Begin your active form like this.

```
ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation'=>false]);
```

Answer (score 43):

```
$form->field($model, 'youAttribute', ['enableClientValidation' => false])->textInput();
```

The `ActiveField` class has a property `enableClientValidation`, you can simply set this property to `false` if you want to disable clientValidation form some fields.

Answer (score 11):

To remove a field from validation:

```
$('#yourFormID').yiiActiveForm('remove', 'yourinputID');
```

To add a field to validation list:

```
$('#yourFormID').yiiActiveForm('add', {
id: 'country',
        name: 'yourinputID',
        container: '.field-inputID', //or your cllass container
        input: '#yourinputID',
        error: '.help-block',  //or your class error
        validate:  function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
            yii.validation.required(value, messages, {message: "Validation Message Here"});
        }
    });
```

And don't forget conditional validation in your model.
[**More info**](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/forms-activeform-js.md)

Comment: Bamm, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can set your active field using this code: (not `active record`, `activefield` exactly)

```
$activeField = $form->field($model, 'someField');
$activeField->enableClientValidation=false;
$activeField ->enableAjaxValidation=false;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try setting default values for attributes that aren't set:

```
[
  // set "username" and "email" as null if they are empty
  [['username', 'email'], 'default'],

  // set "level" to be 1 if it is empty
  ['level', 'default', 'value' => 1],
]
```

[more info here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#handling-empty-inputs)

You can also use **conditional client-side validation** with `"whenClient"` option when defining you validators:

From the manual:

> If you also need to support client-side conditional validation, you
>   should configure the whenClient property which takes a string
>   representing a JavaScript function whose return value determines
>   whether to apply the rule or not. For example,
>
> ```
> [
>     ['state', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
>         return $model->country == 'USA';
>     }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
>         return $('#country').val() == 'USA';
>     }"],
> ]
> ```

Comment: This reloads the page and then validation message shows. Can we prevent page load ?

Answer (score 1):

For your Form, use whenClient:

```
['name', 'required', 'when' => {serverSide Condition),
            'whenClient' => "ut_utils.isAttributeVisible",
        ],
        ['name', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 28],
        ['name', 'trim'],
```

And in ut_utils (JS):

```
/**
     * Useful for FE validation (whenClient) to validate only if visible (ie valid input)
     *
     * @param attribute  Obj containing all sorts of info about attr including container name :-)
     * @param value
     */
    isAttributeVisible: function (attribute, value) {
        return $(attribute.container).is(':visible');
    },
```

You will need to add 'when' to validate serverside too you can add specific logic here or use a scenario to exclude attributes from being validated ...

Answer (score -1):

The method described @hesselek only works if you register a js file in a file with a form , this is important